# How Can I Keep Chrome/Chromium Settings In Sync For Different Windows Accounts?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, chromium

I am using the snapshots (development) version of Chromium, available at: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Win/

I would also like to clarify what I mean by "settings". I am referring to tabs, history, extensions, themes, etc.

I don't personally use Chrome but it is so similar to Chromium that I have decided to list it because it is more popular, and more likely to get my question noticed.

I have two accounts on Windows 8. One is the built-in Administrator account, the other is a Microsoft account. I am aware that from XP onward Windows keeps settings for most programs stored in the Users folder. And I know that Chromium installs itself into the C:\Users\ folder rather than C:\Program Files\Program Files (x86). I originally installed Chromium as the Administrator user. However, when I opened the browser under my Microsoft account (by navigating to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe), I noticed that my settings were different. So I checked the Users folder for my Microsoft account and found that the program hadn't installed itself there. But it did generate some settings files.

My question is, how can I keep the browser's settings in sync for each user account, so that I see EXACTLY the same thing no matter which user is running the browser? I am signed in with my Google account and that has not made much difference. For instance, Google does not save my themes.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

How about creating your "official" copy of settings in some folder accessible by all (such
as in the Public folder), and then replacing the settings folders in each account profile
with a symbolic link to the public one?